# I getting undefined using JSON in jQuery why?

Tags: jquery, json

Im learning some JSON, Im trying to list some data about dogs from twitter...but I can't really present the data...I believe that the error is inside map-method...something I'm missing...thanks for yr help

```
<body>
<h1>U almost there!!</h1>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"> </script>
<script>
// PubSub
(function( $ ) {
    var o = $( {} );

    $.each({
        trigger: 'publish',
        on: 'subscribe',
        off: 'unsubscribe'
    }, function( key, val ) {
        jQuery[val] = function() {
            o[key].apply( o, arguments );
        };
    });
})( jQuery );


$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=dogs&callback=?', function( info) {
    $.publish( 'twitter/info', info );
});

// ...
$.subscribe( 'twitter/info', function( e, info ) {
    $('body').html(
        $.map( info, function( obj) { // <--- here it's error, something Im missing right?
            return '<li>' + obj.text + '</li>';
        }).join('')
    );
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting an actual error? Check your browser console.

Comment: @Chris...no erros listed in console, just the list with undefined items...

Comment: Whats the exact error Message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.....the reason why I was just presenting a list (li- li)
 with undefined items was cuz I forgot to add results from the JSON-object like so:
**info.results** If u do a console.log on the publish-method. This obj. has many other properties insid and we want to target the index of this obj right?, and presente in a list...:)

Answer (score 0):

Change `obj.text` to `$(obj).text();`

Comment: hi there....that's no correct...I've already have the object -> obj.text it's correct